# how to change the value in the set

Tags: python-3.x, set, dataset, rename

I will be appreciated if you can help me how to sort this problem.
Let's say a is such a list and I want to change the name of either Rainfall or age or Odometer

then I want to sort the values like this either '35,23,12,65,34,111,54,23,68,97'as ascending order.

```
a= ['Rainfall,35,23,12,65,34,111,54,23,68,97\n', 'Age,35,23,14,76\n', 'Odometer Reading,35065,67443,23545,12323,72335']
```

I tried:

```
a[0].split(',') = new_name
```

But it did not change.

Could you please help me in order to solve these two issues?
Thanks.

Comment: `a[0].split(',')` is a _function call_, not an _object_. That's why you'll get error message. Also, I'm not sure what are you trying to do. Please include expected output in your question.

Answer (score 1):

To begin, lets look at the instruction a[0].split(',').  This instruction slices the list a at the first element, it then converts the resulting string into a new list separated at the commas.  The result looks like the following:

> ['Rainfall', '35', '23', '12', '65', '34', '111', '54', '23', '68', '97\n']

so performing the a[0].split(',') = new_name operation doesn't make a lot of sense, if you want to change the value of the first element within a[0] utilize the following:

```
a[0] = 'new_name' + a[0][a[0].find(','):]
```

which yields:

```
a = ['new_name,35,23,12,65,34,111,54,23,68,97\n',
 'Age,35,23,14,76\n',
 'Odometer Reading,35065,67443,23545,12323,72335']
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable to which a value is assigned should always be on the left hand side of an expression. So `a[0].split(',') = new_name` should be changed to:
`new_name = a[0].split(',')`
For sorting you could then do the following:

```
readings = new_name[1:]  # takes all the values except the first one
if "\n" in readings[-1]:
   readings[-1] = readings[-1][:-1]  # removes the last \n character
readings = list(map(int, readings))  # converts each value to integer for sorting
readings = sorted(readings)          # sort the value
```